# Indexing other values in a numpy array during array vectorization (1D) without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been tasked with applying a "1-2-1" filter to a numpy array and returning an array of the filtered data. **Without using for loops while loops or list comprehension**.

The "1-2-1" filter maps each point of data to the average of itself twice and its neighbors. For example, if at some point the data contained *...1, 4, 3...* then after applying the "1-2-1" filter the 4 would be replaced with *(1 + 4 + 4 + 3) / 4 = 12 / 4 = 3*.

For example the numpy array `[1, 1, 4, 3, 2]`
Would after the filter is applied produce a numpy array `[1.   1.75 3.   3.   2.  ]`

Since the end points of the data do not have two neighbors the 1-2-1 filter is only applied to the internal len(data) - 2 points, leaving the end points unchanged.

Essentially I need to access the values before and after a given point during numpy array vectorization. For a array that could be of any length. Which as much as I have googled I cannot work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pandas solution**

```
s = pd.Series(l)
```

```
>>> s.rolling(3, center=True).sum().add(s).div(4).fillna(s).values
array([1.  , 1.75, 3.  , 3.  , 2.  ])
```

Step by step:

```
>>> s.rolling(3, center=True).sum().values
array([nan,  6.,  8.,  9., nan])

>>> s.rolling(3, center=True).sum().add(s).values
array([nan,  7., 12., 12., nan])

>>> s.rolling(3, center=True).sum().add(s).div(4).values
array([ nan, 1.75, 3.  , 3.  ,  nan])

>>> s.rolling(3, center=True).sum().add(s).div(4).fillna(s).values
array([1.  , 1.75, 3.  , 3.  , 2.  ])
```

**Numpy solution**

```
a = np.array(l)
```

```
>>> np.concatenate([a[:1], np.convolve(a, [1, 2, 1], mode="valid") / 4, a[-1:]])
```

Step by step:

```
>>> np.convolve(a, [1, 2, 1], mode="valid")
array([ 7, 12, 12])

>>> np.convolve(a, [1, 2, 1], mode="valid") / 4
array([1.75, 3.  , 3.  ])

>>> np.concatenate([a[:1], np.convolve(a, [1, 2, 1], mode="valid") / 4, a[-1:]])
array([1.  , 1.75, 3.  , 3.  , 2.  ])
```

**Performance**

```
%timeit s.rolling(3, center=True).sum().add(s).div(4).fillna(s).values
706 µs ± 4.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.concatenate([a[:1], np.convolve(a, [1, 2, 1], mode="valid") / 4, a[-1:]])
10.8 µs ± 22.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Sadly I think I need to use numpy I’ll give it a shot when I get home. Thanks heaps though

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import circulant

x = np.array([1, 1, 4, 3, 2])

val = np.array([1, 2, 1])
offsets = np.array([0, 1, 2])
col0 = np.zeros(len(x))
col0[offsets] = val

C = circulant(col0).T[:-(len(val) - 1)]
print(C)
```

`C` is essentially a [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) matrix which looks like this:

```
array([[1., 2., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 2., 1.]])
```

Now you can simply compute the filtered output as follows:

```
y = (C @ x) / 4
print(y)
# array([1.75, 3.  , 3.  ])
```

Comment: I can only use numpy but thanks heaps that seems like a smarter solution then what my quiz is asking for.

Comment: I guess if you can figure out a clever way of constructing the circulant matrix using numpy, that will do it!